# How to externalize values in config.groovy

Tags: security, tomcat, grails, configuration

I have a grails application on grails 2.3.5.

It uses AWS accessKey, secretKey, and s3 bucket name:

```
    grails {
        plugin {
            aws {
                credentials {
                    accessKey = "somekey"
                    secretKey = "somesecretkey"
                }
                s3 {
                    bucket = "somebucketname"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a way to externalize these three values so that the people deploying the application can put in values that they want. The way the application is deployed is using Tomcat.

Should these three values be created as environment variables on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way is to use the external configuration framework already provided by Grails. The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) explains this in great detail. Essentially it allows you to put a file on the class path that contains the configuration values that will override your applications settings (if needed).